Badly stuck with proving a limit of a seqeunce is zero
I am badly stuck to prove that $\lim \frac{1 \cdot 5 \cdot 9 \cdot \cdots (4n-3)}{2\cdot 6 \cdot 10 \cdot \cdots (4n - 2)} = 0$. I can prove  $\lim \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \cdots (2n-1)}{2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \cdots (2n)} = 0$, but badly stuck with the above limit. Please help.

Here are very similar problems, the same approach should work: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2028920/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3265425/42969

Try to bound the first sequence by the second, to conclude that the limit is also 0.

@Calvin: I tried this also. Failed.

@Martin: Thank you for the link. Can we have a proof by simple inequality?

HInt: $(\frac{1}{2} )^4 < \frac{ 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 } { 2 \cdot 3\cdot 4 \cdot 5}$. $\quad$ What's the version for the general term?

Using sums is sometimes easier, we define
$$P_n = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{4k-3}{4k-2} \quad \text{and} \quad S_n = \ln(P_n)  $$
We get
$$S_n=\ln \left( \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{4k-3}{4k-2}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left( 1-\frac{3}{4k}\right) - \ln \left( 1-\frac{1}{2k} \right)$$
Now $\ln(1-x) = -x + O(x^2)$ so we get:
$$-S_n =  \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{3}{4k}- \frac{1}{2k} + O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} + O(1) \rightarrow \infty  $$
This means $S_n \to -\infty$ and $P_n = \exp(S_n) \to 0$.

You did it first

@AndreaAveni By 10 seconds maybe, also your answer is a bit faster

Let $A_n$ be $$A_n = \displaystyle\frac{1 \cdot 5 \cdot 9 \cdots (4n-3)}{2 \cdot 6 \cdot 10 \cdots (4n-2)} $$
Note that
\begin{align}
A_n &= \displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n} \displaystyle\frac{4k-3}{4k-2}\\
A_n &= \displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n} \left(1-\displaystyle\frac{1}{4k-2}\right)
\end{align}
Taking logs gives:
\begin{align}
\ln A_n &= \ln \left[\,\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n} \left(1-\displaystyle\frac{1}{4k-2}\right)\right]\\
\ln A_n &= \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} \ln\left(1-\displaystyle\frac{1}{4k-2}\right)
\end{align}
Remember that $\ln(1+x) \leq x$ for all $x>-1$. We can apply this to the summands above.
\begin{align}
\ln A_n &= \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln\left(1-\displaystyle\frac{1}{4k-2}\right)\\
&\leq \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \displaystyle\frac{-1}{4k-2}\\
&= -\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \displaystyle\frac{1}{4k-2}\\
&\leq -\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{n} \displaystyle\frac{1}{4k-2}\\
&\leq -\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{n} \displaystyle\frac{1}{4k}\\
&= -\displaystyle\frac{1}{4}\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{n} \displaystyle\frac{1}{k}
\end{align}
The sum in the last line is the Harmonic series, which diverges. Therefore, in the limit as $n$ goes to infinity, the right-hand-side goes to $-\infty$. Since $\ln A_n$ is bounded above by a series that goes to $-\infty$, we know that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln A_n = -\infty \qquad \implies \qquad \lim_{n\to\infty} A_n = 0$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \displaystyle\frac{1 \cdot 5 \cdot 9 \cdots (4n-3)}{2 \cdot 6 \cdot 10 \cdots (4n-2)} = 0$$

Let's consider $a_n:=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{4k-3}{4k-2}$, we have that
$$\ln(a_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{4k-3}{4k-2}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{4k-2}\right)\leq -\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}$$
This sum is easily seen to diverge to $-\infty$ (indeed it is $\leq -\frac14\ln(n)$), but then $a_n$ converges to zero.

Disclaimer: Even though Martin found similar problems (though not necessarily exhaustive on MSE), those solutions and these presented here all involve bounding logarithms or Gamma functions. There exists a much simplier approach via a comparison test, which hasn't been posted on these MSE problems as yet. In that regard, I consider this "novel to MSE", though obviously it's not earth-shatteringly new. If desired, I can delete this solution.

Define $A_n = \prod_{k=1}^n{ \frac{ 4k-3}{4k-2} } $ and $B_n = \prod_{k=1}^n  \frac{ (4k-3)(4k-2)(4k-1)(4k) } { (4k-2)(4k-1)(4k)(4k+1) } $.
Observe that since $ (\frac{ 4k-3}{4k-2})^4 < \frac{ (4k-3)(4k-2)(4k-1)(4k) } { (4k-2)(4k-1)(4k)(4k+1) }$ holds termwise, hence $A_n ^4 < B_n$.
Finally, since OP can show that $ \lim B_n = 0 $, hence (with a small bit of work)  $\lim A_n = 0 $.
